# How to enable/disable the 2 instance of bvalidator

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I do have 2 instance of bvalidator (http://bmauser.github.io/bvalidator - in case if someone doesnt know it) running on my form.

First instance validates all form, second instance validates partially but the same form.

The form does have 2 `buttons`:

First button saves the form data if it does validate it with the first instance.

Second button should save the form when the secondInstance of validation is true.

However, I can't figure out how to **disable** one instance and run another instance.

As en example, I do have this input in my form:

```
<input id="recordId" name="recordId" type="text"  value="$!currentmm.recordId" data-bvalidator="digit,required" data-bvalidator-modifier="myDigitsModifier" data-secondinstance="digit,required" data-secondinstance-modifier="myDigitsModifier" />
```

As you can see it has 2 instance of `bvalidator`. Default: bvalidator and secondinstance.

I use this code:

```
$('#myForm').data('bValidator').destroy();  // I destroy the first instance     
$('#myForm').data('bValidators').secondinstance.validate(); //initialize the second instance                            
if ($('#myForm').data('bValidators').secondinstance.isValid()) {
//if the second instance is valid the do some job
}
```

But id doesn't work. When I destroy the `first` instance it seems like it does **destroy** the whole `bvalidator instance`..

EDIT:

For example this is a part of my form, and I've added 2 instance of the bvalidator for the same input boxes with the same condition of bvalidation:

```
                   <h1><label style="width:350px;";>$i18n.getString( "marriage_record" )</label>
        <label style="font-size:8pt;";>$i18n.getString( "record_number" ) </label>
        <input id="recordId" name="recordId" type="text"  value="$!currentMarriage.recordId" data-bvalidator="digit,required" data-bvalidator-modifier="myDigitsModifier" data-secondinstance="digit,required" data-secondinstance-modifier="myDigitsModifier" class="dontcheck"/>
        <label style="font-size:8pt;width:200px;";>$i18n.getString( "registration_date" ) </label>
        <input id="registrationDate" name="registrationDate" type="text" value="$!vfh.formatDateForInput($!currentMarriage.registrationDate)" data-bvalidator="required"  data-secondinstance="required" class="dontcheck" />
        </h1>
```

So, what I did next in the code:

When the first button has been clicked I call:

```
$('#addMarriageRecordForm').data('bValidator').destroy();
```

I thought that call will destroy the first instance of the bvalidator. Then I call this:

```
$('#addMarriageRecordForm').data('bValidators').secondinstance.validate();
```

According to my logic now it has to validate the form with the secondinstance, but unfortunately it throws an error once I destroy the first instance of the bvalidator.. That's what I was thinking to do, multi instance.

Does it supported in the current version of bvalidator? I read the js code, and I think once I call the destroy function it does destroy all instances of bvalidator.. Is it the way it works? I think it should be awesome if we could just disable/enable some particular bvalidator instance based on need.

Comment: You are right there is a problem with destroy() function I'll fix that. You can disable validation if you put data-bvalidator-return="true" on the <form>. That was not documented, but now is here: 
http://bmauser.github.io/bvalidator/#exampleForceValidation

Comment: destroy() should work like expected in v1.0.3

Comment: @user570605, cool.. I'll give it a try later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke validation with:

```
$('#button1').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#myForm').data('bValidator').validate()) {
       // save form
       ...
    }
}
```

If you need to submit the form after validation, you can disable validaton on submit event for the instances with `data-secondinstance-option-validate-on-submit="false"` and `data-bvalidator-option-validate-on-submit="false"`attributes on the `<form>` element. If `#button1` is submit button the code can be:

```
var skipFirstInstance = false;

$("form").submit(function(e) {       

    if(skipFirstInstance)
        return;

    if ($('#myForm').data('bValidator').validate()) {
       // save form
       ...
    }
    else{
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

$('#button2').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#myForm').data('bValidators').secondinstance.validate()) {
       // save form
       ...
       // disable first instance validation
       skipFirstInstance = true;

       // submit the form
       $('form').submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I need to submit the form once the validation is done, but the thing is that this code will not work.. Even though I didnt call the validation for the first instance the second instance will keep validating the form, even if it has just the first validation `tag`. I need multi instance, as I described.